# Getting statistics of the activity of my engine

Tags: java, statistics

One of my application is an engine that executes some complex calculations. These calculations may take several hours. I want to know the activity of this engine among time.

If you are using H[udson CI server](http://hudson-ci.org/), there is such a feature in `Administration > Usages statistics` option. Here is an example:

[image]

In my application, I already have a function that returns the number of calculations. So my idea is to periodically call this method, for example every 10 minutes (using [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/)) in order to retrieve the number of running calculations and store it in a `int[]`. Every day, this `int[]` is stored in an external file, and cleaned. So after some days, the content of this file will look like:

```
data.20101008=1;2;1;0;1;1;0;0;0;0;....;0
data.20101009=1;0;1;1;0;0;0;0;3;2;....;0
data.20101010=1;2;1;0;1;1;2;3;4;4;....;2
...
```

(I simplified a little this processing, as I want to update this file more frequently, in case of engine shutdown, or something like that)

To summarize, my idea is to store in a `properties` file the number of running calculations for a specific day. Eventually, I can provide a function that returns this data as a `Map<Date, int[]>`.

Finally, I will use [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) to display these data in a graphical

What do you think of this idea? Any advice to enhance this process?

Note that this functionality is one a *nice to have* feature, so I don't want to build too complex systems.

I am using Java 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a properties file and JFreeChart, maybe consider using a [RRDTool](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/) Java implementation like [RRD4J](http://code.google.com/p/rrd4j/). From the RRDTool website:

> RRDtool is the OpenSource industry standard, high performance data logging and graphing system for time series data.

Answer (score 2):

For simple ad-hoc monitoring by a human operator, you can simply use JMX. With JConsole (ships with the JDK) you can connect to a running java process and it will do nice graphs of CPU and memory usage, number of live threads, any many more. Using MBeans, you can expose current values over JMX, and use JConsole to chart them  (while it is connected, of course).